# Hover animation not smooth

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

I'm dipping my toes into web design for now and I'm trying to replicate the "buy more" button animation from here( https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=67539 ). While I did find a solution for the border, I can't make a smooth animation for the icon(I am using font awesome), instead it just jumps directly.
Thanks in advance for the help

My CSS is this for the button is:

```
and the html for it is `<a href="#" class="navbar__btn">Buy now&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-level-down-alt navbar__btn--i"></i></a>`

.navbar__btn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 7rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}

.navbar__btn:after {
  margin-top: .3rem;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-bottom: solid 2px #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:  0% 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar__btn:hover:after {
  transform:scaleX(1.2);
}

.navbar__btn:hover .navbar__btn--i {
  left: 7rem;
}

.navbar__btn--i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  transition: all 1s linear 1s;
}
```

And the html is

```
<a href="#" class="navbar__btn">Buy now&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-level-down-alt navbar__btn--i"></i></a>
```

Comment: the transition work on the change of the same attribute. If you want to apply the transition on the "left" attribute you need to specify that attribute in both declarations ergo you need to specify the left on the last ".navbar__btn--i"

Comment: That's something to remember, thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

Replace the appropriate icon. I designed it according to the link. You can adjust the delays to your liking

```css
.navbar__btn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 7rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}

.navbar__btn:after {
  margin-top: .3rem;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-bottom: solid 2px #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:  0% 100%;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar__btn:hover:after  {
  transform:scaleX(1.3);
}

.navbar__btn:hover .navbar__btn--i {
  right: -20px;
}

.navbar__btn--i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right:-10px;
  line-height:0px;
  transition: all .3s linear 0s;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div style="heigth:100px;width:500px;background:red;padding:5px;">
  <a href="#" class="navbar__btn">Buy now&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-arrow-right navbar__btn--i"></i></a>
</div>
```